# node/[nid]/edit does nothing. how to troubleshoot?

Tags: 6, nodes

I'm trying to edit a node in Drupal 6. The edit tab is visible and clickable and everything, and directs to the proper path (/node/[nid]/edit) but... nothing happens. How do I troubleshoot this? I don't see any weird edit page templates in the theme or anything. I didn't develop this site or this theme but am now maintaining it. How do I begin troubleshooting something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first step would be to watch the request with Firefox's Live HTTP Headers.  This will tell you if the request is actually going out or not.

If it is, then you need to check server logs to see if the request is being processed.  You may also need to add some `watchdog()` calls in the core node.module to track it down.

If the request isn't going through, then I suspect you have some rogue Javascript that is intercepting the click.  Disable JS and retest.  Another possibility could be that you have a CSS positioned element over the tab, and that is actually catching the click event.  Go through the body with Inspect Element and double check all of that.

Comment: Good call on the JavaScript. Disabling it fixed the problem.